# Pycharm debugging console not printing

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2020.1.2 and I am having the following problem:
Normally, while debugging when I click on "Evaluate" a window opens in which I can do debugging. The problem is that that if I ask it to print something, it does not show in the Python console... And before (when using older version of PyCharm), it used to show it.

Here, I wanted to print "5" but when I click on evaluate nothing happens in the console... (see the screenshot)

[image]

I have just installed the latest version of PyCharm on a new computer so maybe there is some setting that I have to activate?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I found out that actually no output gets printed, so it is not relate to the debugger. Continuing to investigate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the issue was that I was running pytest + scriptname and not just the scriptname. I had to add another configuratio in "Edit Configurations" and then it ran properly.

More details on that here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007736899-PyCharm-Run-command-does-not-print-python-console-does